# Determining two parameter family of solutions given $Ax = b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Question:

Assume that $ A\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1\\
-1\\
2\\\end{array}\right] = 0 = A\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2\\
0\\
3\\\end{array}\right] $.

Show that $ \ x_{0} = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2\\
-1\\
3\\\end{array}\right]$ is a solution to $ \ Ax = b$. Find a two parameter family of solution to $ \ Ax = b$.

My attempt:

We know that $ a_{1} -a_{2} + 2a_{3} = 0$ and $ \ 2a_{1} + 3a_{3} = 0$ where $ a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}$ are columns of $ \ A$. I am not sure how to use this to show that $ \ x_{0} $is a solution and to find a two parameter family of solutions.

Comment: But what is $b$?

Comment: Im not sure. This is exactly what the question in my textbook says

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still at a loss attempting to understand what $b$ is. It definitely matters.

Comment: By definition it is the coefficient matrix of the system

Comment: You said that $b$ is the coefficient matrix -- no, it's not. $A$ is the coefficient matrix of the system, if we're speaking in terms of systems of equations; and then $b$ is the column-vector of the right-hand sides of those equations. Right now this question doesn't make much sense. But it would make perfect sense if instead of "Show that..." it said "Assume that...".

Comment: Sorry I meant to say constant matrix. My bad.

Comment: This is what my textbook says.

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Agree with zipirovich. If you replace "Show that $x_0$ is a solution to $Ax+b$" with "Assume that $x_0$ is a solution to $Ax=b$..." then "Find a two parameter family of solutions..." is a nice conceptual question that fits with the other information given and has a straightforward solution. Even if what you wrote is what is in the book, the authors almost certainly *meant* to write "assume that" (or perhaps $b$ is defined in the text or in an earlier problem). Recommend you amend the problem and work the modified version.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Could you please give me a hint on how to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Assuming, as discussed in the comments, that the authors meant for you to *assume* $Ax_0=b,$ we can find another solution to $Ax=b$ as follows:

Let $y=(1,-1,2)^T$ and consider $x_1 = x_0 + y.$ Then we have $$ Ax_1 = A(x_0+y) = Ax_0+Ay  =b + 0 = b.$$

So $x_1$ is also a solution.

Now can you use this idea to find an infinite number of solutions? A two-parameter family?

Comment: $ \ x = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}\\\end{array}\right]$ =   $ \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2\\
-1\\
3\\\end{array}\right]$ + $ \ s \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1\\
-1\\
2\\\end{array}\right]$ +  $ \ t \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2\\
0\\
3\\\end{array}\right]$

Comment: Is this what the question is looking for?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel yes, that's what i had in mind, anyway

Comment: So they just want us to express the solutions in $ \ x_{2} = x_{0} + x_{1}$ form where $ \ x_{0}$ is a particular solution to the system and $ \ x_{1}$ are all the solutions to the associated homogenous system right?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel yes